# Is that possible for an array to be divergent sequence but convergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there possible to construct an array such that

when it is consider as a sequence, it diverges. But as series, it converges ??

Comment: I'm afraid that even after you'll define mathematically "array" your question won't make sense...

Comment: A series is a sequence of partial sums.

Answer (score 2):

A necessary condition for $\sum a_n$ to converge is that $a_n \rightarrow 0$.